# Проблема с перебором элементов в цикле python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Должно получиться что–то типа игры - человек вводит число, а машина перебирает варианты, пытаясь его угадать. 
Сама проблема в `if` - даже если задаваемое число равно выводу кода, равенство не выполняется.

Я начинающий и любая обоснованная критика или замечание будут восприняты с благодарностью

```
    print ('choose number from 0 up to 10 - ')
    choice = int(input())

    L = [[i+1] for i in range(10)]
    shuffle(L)

    for i in L:
        if i == choice:
            print("that is")
            print(i)
            break
        else:
            print("next time")
            print(i)
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде есть две проблемы:

1. Вы забыли импортировать функцию `shuffle` из библиотеки `random`
2. Вы заполняете массив `L` не целыми числами, а массивами единичной длины. Это происходит потом, что `[i+1]` на самом деле возвращает *массив* а не скаляр.

Правильный, работоспособный код, может иметь вид:

```
from random import shuffle

print ('choose number from 0 up to 10 - ')
choice = int(input())

L = [i+1 for i in range(10)]
shuffle(L)

for i in L:
    if i == choice:
        print("that is")
        print(i)
        break
    else:
        print("next time")
        print(i)
```

Comment: не, ну я хотел;)

Comment: @dDevil, увы, я оказался первым))

Comment: Import shuffle я забыл написать, похоже :) а вот про массив не знал. Всем спасибо!